# "object not found" error when using the filter verb

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm taking a data analysis course in grad school and trying my best to learn R. I've taken some courses on Datacamp but just now have tried working on my coursework which is of course different.

So on to the error.

I have a data sat which I've loaded called "BBB.Rdata"

now in analyzing the data I've tried to start using the arrange and filter verbs for one of the columns. The data set has individual observations by gender.

I tried

```
BBB %>%
    filter(gender == "M")
```

To which I get the error

> "Error in filter(gender == M) : object 'gender' not found"

When I just type the "BBB" into the console it shows me the data frame where you can very clearly see in the header that "gender" does exist. Because it is one of the column headers am I missing a step here?

I imagine this is a pretty basic, dumb error I'm making but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Couple things - 1) what's the `+` doing in `bbb %>% + filter(gender = "M")`?  You don't need it.  2) is your dataframe called `bbb` or `BBB`?  R is case sensitive.

Comment: I apologize, that's a typo on my part, the data is bbb, I'm not sure why I typed BBB but I've been doing this correctly in the console.

Comment: Should be `filter(gender == "M")` with the double equals sign.

Comment: Ah! Yes, the "+" was screwing things up.

on my online course it had me separating the pipe with a space in between but this throws an error in the console. 

Thanks for the help!! Now off to analyzing that data!